# Code Performance - Data from two different databases populating view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

Basically I have an MVC site which stores contacts, with various information such as Name, Company etc., and these Contacts visits to various locations are also logged in a separate database when they check in somewhere.

So Contacts and Visits are held in separate databases.

I have a tab within my MVC site which displays the profiles of the users Contacts and as their presence is detected at a location that profile rises to the top of the list.

I have built this and it works absolutely fine. However for large numbers of contacts the page takes that long to populate that it times out. So here's what my process is.

Firstly I get all of the current users Contacts and create a list of view models from the data:

```
var model = DbContext.Contacts.Where(x => x.Organisation.Id == org.Id).ToList().Select(x => new AttendeeViewModel
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            Company = x.Company,
            Position = x.Position,
            DateJoined = x.DateJoined == Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000") ? DateTime.Now : x.DateJoined,
            lastVisit = findLastVisit(x)                
        }).ToList();
```

As you can see for the lastVisit I call a method called `findLastVisit()`:

```
public Visit findLastVisit(Contact contact)
    {

        var date = DateTime.Now;

        var item = inboundContext.Visits.
                   Where(d => LocIds.Contains(d.LocationId) &&
                   d.ContactId == contact.Id &&
                   d.DateOfContact <= date)
                   .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateOfContact)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

        if (item != null)
        {
            return item;
        }
        else { return new Visit { }; }

    }
```

And then in the view I display this information for each profile, basically in a list. So as the page is loaded this entire list should initially populate the page.

So the basic functionality flow I require is:

- Fetch all users contacts from context1
- Create view models using the last recorded visit of that contact from context2

I have tested and the problem is the `findLastVisit()` method being called once for every contact in the list. It's this process of fetching the last Visit for every Contact that's taking too long to complete when numbers get too large. It's pretty inefficient....if I ignore the lastVisit data then it loads very quickly.

Just wondering if anyone could see a more time efficient way of doing this or if I need to instead look into other options like rendering the view without the last Visit information and the user revealing this information by clicking on their profile.

JK

Answer (score 0):

Probably most solutions to this will involve splitting those queries apart and crafting WHERE part so that you query each database once and both have ClientId columns. Then you could join those on ContactId columns having final result.

This could be done on various levels, but one simple change you could try would be very similar with what you have within 2nd query - LocIds.Contains(..) :

1) select from DbContext.Contacts into temporary List without findLastVisit() call,

2) select relevant clientId-s and pass those to 2nd query

3) select all last visit dates for clients in the Ids list and include CLientID column in the results

4) join 1st query and 2nd query results on ClientId column into your model.

Note : You did not mention what you mean by "large numbers of contacts the page", but I assumed here that is a "page" in web sense, something like 10-100 rows.

Comment: Yeah my test is for around 1000 Contacts just want to see how fast I can get it before making a decision on simplifying the view. Thanks for the reply. I also think I should change my second query to only include last visits using Distinct and grouping by ContactId...I'll give it a go now